# python numpy data type error and extremely inefficient use of pyplot :(

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matplotlib

[Using windows 10 and python 3.5 with newest modules]

Hello!

I have two slightly different problems that belong together because one is the buggy solution of the other. The first function here is extremely slow with datapoints over 75000 and does not work with 150000. This on does exactly what I want though.

```
#I call the functions like this:
plt.plot(logtime[:recmax-(degree*2-1)] - (logtime[0]-degree), smoothListTriangle(cpm, degree), color="green", linewidth=2, label="Smoothed n="+degree)
plt.plot(logtime[:recmax] - logtime[0], smoothListGaussian2(str(cpm), degree), color="lime", linewidth=5, label="")

#And cpm is always:
cpm = cpm.astype(int) #Array of big number of values


def smoothListTriangle(cpm,degree):  #Thank you Scott from swharden.com!
    weight=[]  
    window=degree*2-1
    smoothed=[0.0]*(len(cpm)-window)

    for x in range(1,2*degree):
        weight.append(degree-abs(degree-x))

    w=np.array(weight)

    for i in range(len(smoothed)):  
        smoothed[i]=sum(np.array(cpm[i:i+window])*w)/float(sum(w))
    #Very, VERY slow...
    return smoothed
```

The higher "degree" is the longer it takes. But with lesser degree it would not look good.

...

The second function here should be (way?) more efficient, but i cant resolve the data type error:

```
def smoothListGaussian2(myarray, degree):
    myarray = np.pad(myarray, (degree-1,degree-1), mode='edge')
    window = degree*2-1
    weight = np.arange(-degree+1, degree)/window
    weight = np.exp(-(16*weight**2))
    weight /= sum(weight)
    #weight = weight.astype(int)    #Does throw the "invalid literal" error
    smoothed = np.convolve(myarray, weight, mode='valid')
    return smoothed

    #TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Im desperately trying to resolve this data type error here with numpy. Its killing me! IT seems to be the array "weight" thats the one who's float64, but converting it throws more errors like:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[31 31 33 ..., 48 49 51]'
```

So... Im new to python and use this to log data from my geiger counter. Do you have any idea how to either make the first function WAY more efficient or resolve the error in the second? Im at a loss here.

I found the scripts here: http://www.swharden.com/wp/2008-11-17-linear-data-smoothing-in-python/#comments (I found Scotts other triangle-smooth-function on this site, but i couldnt get this to work either. Its more complicated)

Note that the number of data points are depending on the length in seconds of the measurement and this length can very well be several days. I guess one million data points and more are not unusual.

Thank you!

Comment: First, I can't reproduce the invalid literal error, `weight.astype(int)` works without a problem for me (although I'm on Python2.7, but I doubt that's the reason). Second, if you convert `weight` to ints you'll get 0s only since all your numbers are less than 1. Is this really what you want?

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, your myarray is in the wrong format, I guess. (its: 33, 34, 30,...55, 49, 48) I was just desperately trying to make it work. Since I'm on Windows and python 3.5 and the original script is for unix and python 2.7 I was always fighting with data types . Its probably version specific.

Comment: `myarray` is irrelevant as far as `weight` definition and manipulation goes...

Comment: Is there an alternative for convolve then? I do know that doing it manually instead of calling functions is faster, but that was c++ compiling.

Comment: Hmpf... If I could at least understand why it is so slow. I need some input :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had a revelation of some sort. All i had to do is convert the "myarray" to float before convolving.

I had to do so many conversions to make the whole code work correctly, its ridiculous! I thought this is easy in Python, but no.. :(( Seems to me that c++ is better in that case.

```
def smoothListGaussian2(myarray, degree):
    myarray = np.pad(myarray, (degree - 1, degree - 1), mode='edge')
    window = degree * 2 - 1
    weight = np.arange(-degree + 1, degree) / window
    weight = np.exp(-(16 * weight ** 2))
    weight /= sum(weight)

    myarray = myarray.astype(float)
    smoothed = np.convolve(myarray, weight, mode='valid')
    return smoothed
```

Since this works now I coud test the speed and its pretty fast. I cant see a difference in speed between 40k and 150k data points anymore. cool

Comment: All my problems I had with these programs are so easy to solve. I should think more before asking. :D